# Unexpected token { error when returning hash

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my react code, I have the following method which returns a hash:

```
foo: function() {
     return {{a: 1,b: 2,c: 3}, {d: 4}};
}
```

On the line with the `return` statement I am getting this however:

`Parse Error: Line 141: Unexpected token { while parsing file`

Why is this occurring?

Comment: Did you mean to return an array of two objects? `[{a: 1,b: 2,c: 3}, {d: 4}]`?  If not, what?  What you have isn't valid.

Comment: an object has to have property keys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting that error because when the parser sees the first '`{`', it expects to find a *key* next, but instead finds another '`{`', which is invalid syntax. Refer to the proper syntax for [Object Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Object_literals).

Since there's nothing descriptive enough in the provided code to tell what you're trying to return beside that you're trying to return a *hash*, I can only guess that you are either intending to return 4 named numbers:

```
return { a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4 };
```

or two nested objects with named numbers; **in which case you must provide a key for each nested object**:

```
return { nested_a: { a:1, b:2, c:3 }, nexted_b: { d:4 } };
```

To understand why, think about the code that will be receiving the returned value from your `foo` function.

```
var foo_result = foo();
```

If you want to access `a`, for example, how would you reference it? With the original object you are returning (`{ { a:1, b:2, c:3 }, { d:4 } }`) there would be no way to reference that first inner object containing `a`, `b` and `c`.

```
var a_result = foo_result.?.a; // no way to get at that variable
```

Which is why every property in an object needs a *key*. Following my example above:

```
var a_result = foo_result.nested_a.a; // this works
```

### Note about array declaration

When you see an [array literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Array_literals) declared like:

```
var an_array = [ { a:1, b:2, c:3 }, { d:4 } ];
```

This is ok because arrays have an implicit way to reference their elements; by their *index*.

```
var a_result = an_array[ 0 ].a; // array indices start at 0
```